# How to divide a data file's column A by column B using Perl

Tags: linux, perl, command

I was given a text file with a whole bunch of data sorted in columns. Each of the columns are
separated by commas.

How could I divide a column by another column to print an output answer? I am using Perl right now now so it has to be done in Perl. How could I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 open (FILE, 'census2008.txt');
 while (<FILE>) {
     chomp;
     ($sumlev, $stname,$ctyname,$popestimate2008,$births2008,$deaths2008) = split(",");
 }
 close (FILE);
 exit;
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

There are several options:

- Read the file in line by line, [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the columns on `','` and divide the relevant columns (don't forget to handle the divide-by-zero error)
- Do the same thing as a one-liner:

  ```
  $ perl -F/,/ -lane 'print( $F[1] == 0 ? "" : $F[3]/$F[1] )' file.txt
  ```
- Utilize a ready-to-use CPAN module like [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV)

---

Of course, there are more unorthodox/crazy/unspeakable alternatives à la TMTOWTDI ™, so one could:

- Parse out the relevant columns with a regex and divide the matches:

  ```
  if (/^\d*,(\d+),\d*,(\d+)/) { say $2/$1 if $2 != 0; }
  ```
- Do it with `s///e`:

  ```
  $ perl -ple 's!^\d*,(\d+),\d*,(\d+).*$! $2 == 0 ? "" : $2/$1 !e' file.txt;
  ```
- Get the shell to do the dirty work via backticks:

  ```
  sub print_divide { say `cat file.txt | some_command_line_command` }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# divides column 1 by column 2 of some ','-delimited file, 
# read from standard input.
# usage:
# $ cat data.txt | 8458760.pl 

while (<STDIN>) {
    @values = split(/,/, $_);
    print $values[0] / $values[1] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: did u just make values an array?

Comment: I was just wondering. can you explain ur split function? I am new to this and not sure what it is saying.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed width columns of data you could use 'unpack' along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($sumlev,$stname,$ctyname,$popest,$births,$deaths)
        = unpack("A2xA10xA15xA7xA5xA5");
    printf "%-15s %4.2f\n", $ctyname, $births/$deaths;
}
__DATA__
10,Main      ,My City        ,  10000,  200,  150
12,Poplar    ,Somewhere      ,   3000,   90,  100
13,Maple     ,Your Place     ,   9123,  100,   90
```